# Using lodash/underscore how can I update the value of the key

Tags: object, lodash

I have to convert the date into a timestamp using Date.parse().Each time I find the key "Date__c".

```
[
   {
      "Date__c":"07/30/2015",
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   },
   {
      "Date__c":"07/30/2015",
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   },
   {
      "Date__c":"07/30/2015",
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   }
]

To become


[
   {
      "Date__c":1438185600000,
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   },
   {
      "Date__c":1438185600000,
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   },
   {
      "Date__c":1438185600000,
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
   {
      "Date__c":"07/30/2015",
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   },
   {
      "Date__c":"07/30/2015",
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   },
   {
      "Date__c":"07/30/2015",
      "End_Time__c":"14:00",
      "Start_Time__c":"07:00"
   }
]

_.map(arr, 
    function (a) { 
        return _.mapValues(a, function(v, k) { 
                return "Date__c" == k ? new Date(v).valueOf() : v; 
            }
        )
    }
)
```